# How to pass the result array from a form to another form by php

Tags: php, forms

I'm having two forms in a row. I would like to make the user fill in the first form, and after they submit the from, I'm going to provide another form to let the user fill in their names.

Well, right now I have couple ideas how to do this, but just out of curiosity. Is there any other way that I can do this?

The first idea is to post the first form, and use `json_encode()` to convert the array to a string, then pass it to the 2nd form as a hidden input.

The second idea is to put all the data from the 1st from in the url, so the 2nd form can access these data by using the get method. However, if the data is too large, this will not work.

I'm looking for a way that I can post all data from both 1st form and 2nd form at once, then save them in the database. I don't want to divide the insert data process into 2 steps, since all these data are in the same table.

Comment: well, saving in the session maybe another way. If there is no other good way, I'm going to use the session

Comment: Sessions or db.